# Programatically create pages for inline visualforce

Tags: apex, metadata-api

I have following visualforce page available on Lead layout for adding as inline visualforce page.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Lead" extensions="CloudFilesController">
   <!-- code here-->
    <script>
      var objectName = 'Lead';
      // code here
    </script>
    <!-- code here-->
</apex:page>
```

Except the standard controller and a javascript variable 'ojectName' all the code is same for all objects. I want to automate the creation of these pages for other objects and present user with a setup screen where I list all objects and user can create these by a button click for each objects and then add to Page layout. One way of doing it will be metadata api. I want to do it all in apex so I will probably have to use https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi apex wrapper for metadata api.

Are there other ways to do it, any pure apex way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other alternative will be using tooling API for this requirement.Using tooling API to create these pages should be simple using HTTP callout with session Id.